# how is clipping done for this figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

Could you help draw this figure by clipping? Not because I am lazy but I read the tikz tutorial, that is so hard. I have some other figures like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=1]{standalone}
\degrees[6]
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pscustom[fillstyle=eofill,fillcolor=yellow]{\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{\pscircle(2;\i){2}}}
    \pscircle{2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

No clipping needed:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, fill=blue!50!cyan, draw=orange]
\fill [draw, even odd rule] 
  \foreach \i in {1,...,6}{ (\i*60+30:1) circle (1) };
\draw circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And without the `even odd rule`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[very thick, fill=blue!50!cyan, draw=orange]
\filldraw \foreach \i in {1,...,6}{ [rotate=\i*60]
    (0:0) arc (210:90:1) arc (30:150:1) arc(90:-30:1) };
\draw circle (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(the result is the same as above).